# Angular use variable value as opposed to string of variable name

Tags: angular

I am working with an array that looks something like this:

```
[
   {
     f_name: "c_name",
     title: "k c name",
     con_name: "cname",
     path: "this.dialogData.name"
   },
   {
     f_name: "c_num",
     title: "k c num",
     con_name: "cnum",
     path: "this.dialogData.number"
   }
]
```

In the html file, I'm looping through this array as follows:

```
        <mat-form-field *ngFor ="let f of fields">
            <mat-label>{{f.title}}</mat-label>
            <input  formControlName={{f.con_name}} matInput name={{f.con_name}} value={{f.path}}>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Everything is working as expected except the `{{f.path}}` is coming up as the string as opposed to the variable.

So for example, in the first question, the value is set to `this.dialogData.name` as opposed to `test_name` which is the value that corresponds to the variable `this.dialogData.name`.

Is there anything I can do to refer to the underlying variable? As opposed to having the value as the path string.

Comment: This doesn't look right. If you have the object `this.dialogData` when creating the `fields` array, why not initialize the property `path` with the values of `"this.dialogData.name"` instead of a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding from my comment, I believe you actually tried to initialize the properties `path` in each element to the properties in `this.dialogData` instead of assigning the strings. In that case, you could remove the enclosing quotations for the `path` properties.

Try the following

```js
fields = [
  {
    f_name: "c_name",
    title: "k c name",
    con_name: "cname",
    path: this.dialogData.name         // <-- no quotations
  },
  {
    f_name: "c_num",
    title: "k c num",
    con_name: "cnum",
    path: this.dialogData.number       // <-- no quotations
  }
];
```